# Maya selection import

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to figure if it's possible to import a maya file into a Maya scene, but only certain things objects (such as locators named "xyz" and it's animation) but skip everything else. (I'm not looking to import a folder amount of files, but select certain elements from a maya file)

I've been searching low and wide for something resembling what I'm after, but I' can't seem to find it.

Is it possible with Maya's Python API?

Comment: Pretty sure neither api or python won't support selective import yet :( .. but you can make it works like saving header info while on filesave callback and then import read that data then remove stuff based on user selection. Although this also time consuming same as normal import

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you will be much better off solving this problem at an earlier stage, than waiting until Maya importing.

If it's a .ma file,  you can probably parse and do filtering on it, and save the relevant elements into another .ma file. Otherwise I found this forum question seems to be relevant:

http://tech-artists.org/t/loading-mb-ma-outside-of-maya/2344